# Is it possible to define custom genertors in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, yield

The following code is transformed into a generator by the Python compiler:

```
def myGenerator(max):
  for i in range(max):
    yield i
```

It can be used with this code:

```
>>> gen = myGenerator(10)
>>> next(gen)
0
>>> next(gen)
1
```

If I query the class of gen, I get `generator`.

Is it possible to use a custom generator class? Let's say I would like to have a percent property on `gen`.

```
>>> gen.Percent
10
```

As far as I have understood generators, they implement several methods. Can I build a generator like object by myself and extend it by custom methods?

Comment: Yes, of course; see https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typeiter

Comment: I'm using these generators in a co-routine based parser. So my parser uses `gen.send(..)` to send tokens to the co-routine. Implementing the iterator protocol by hand does not offer the co-routine feature, does it?

Comment: You can implement `__aiter__` if you're using `asyncio` - https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#asynchronous-iterators.

Comment: Is this [PEP 0492](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/) related? So this feature is available since Python 3.5?